# How to suppress initial validation error in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

ASP.NET MVC3 view displays validation error if get request is invoked. How to show validation error only if post request is used like in MVC2 ?

View:

`<%= Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Error") %>`

Controller:

```
namespace Store.Controllers
{
    public class CheckoutController : MyApp.Controllers.ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Address()
        {
            return View(new AddressViewModel());
        }


        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Address(AddressViewModel model, string name) {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

         return RedirectToAction("Payment");
         }
       }
       }
```

Comment: ValidationSummary triggers only if your Modelstate is invalid

Comment: `new AddressViewModel()` creates invalid model: required fields are empty. Error message apepars if form is initially shown. How to suppress it initially so that error message appers only if form with invalid data is posted by user ? I tried `ModelState.IsValid = true` but IsValid is read-only.

Comment: @Andrus: Try  clearing the `ModelState` if you do not want to show the errors. This can be done only in the Get Method.

Comment: I added `ModelState.Clear()` before `return View(new AddressViewModel())` but error message still appears

Comment: Your Model state is obviously Invalid,why do you want to circumvent that issue.Does it happening during the initial view rendering or during the post

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` is true in Address() method so it is valid.  Message appears in the initial view rendering. Why this message appears in MVC3 and how to suppress it? All validation is done in Address(AddresViewModel model,... ) method called if submit button is pressed.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto . Adding `Html.EnableClientValidation(false)` to view seems to fix it. No idea why this is required in MVC3. Same code worked in MVC2+.NET 3.5 without disabling client validation. There is no any client side validation in view.

Comment: this shouldn't happen try starting from scratch in a new project, have just a page with a form and use a viewmodel with a few properties. I have this page http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/Unobtrusive and I'm using attributes on the viewmodel and unobtrusive client side validation as well, and  no validation messages are displayed when rendering the page on the get request (it's MVC4 atm, but it was the same in MVC3 and it was working the same)